# I'm a getting stuck with initializing subclass of UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, initialization

I want to create a `UIView` by code and I need to know 4 variables to draw this `UIView`.
But I can't initialize this subclass.

Here is my code:

```
class CardView: UIView, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate{
    private(set) var character: Int
    private(set) var numberOfCharacters: Int
    private(set) var shading: Int
    private(set) var color: Int
    private(set) var identifier: Int

    init(frame: CGRect, card: Card) {
        self.character = card.character
        self.numberOfCharacters = card.numberOfCharacters
        self.color = card.color
        self.shading = card.shading
        self.identifier = card.identifier

        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder) //Error: Property 'self.character' not initialized at super.init call
    }
}
```

Did I miss anything?

Comment: What error does it show?

Comment: Editted, @RakeshaShastri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error appears because you are required to give every non-initialised property a value in every designated initialiser, before you call `super.init` You haven't given a value to all your properties in the `init(coder:)` initialiser, hence the error.

You can just call `fatalError` in the initialiser:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Calling `fatalError` here is acceptable because you are only creating your `UIView` by code, so the above initialiser will not be called. It *will* be called when you load your view from an XIB or storyboard, in which case you have to decode the values from the `NSCoder` and assign the properties.

Comment: Thanks Sweeper... I fixed it... But what if I initialize uiview either in code or in storyboard ?

Comment: @TheDev311 then you need to call the `decode...(forKey:)` methods and assign your properties.

Comment: I will search that.. Thanks Sweeper.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is with the variables, those are not initialized so only you may get the errors. So, please set some value to the variables are declare them like below:

```
private(set) var character: Int!
```

Comment: Thanks JM.. I fixed it..  I shouldn't call "super.init(coder: aDecoder)"  because I just initialize UIView in code